# change agent.name | Azure devops agents

Tags: azure-devops, agent

is it possible to change the agent.name? without to delete the agent and reinstall?

linux system

picture

[image: 1]

I try to vim the config.sh and I didn't find that variable

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no such method can directly change the agent name without re-installing the self-hosted agent.

The agent name is a primary key in the backend. We need to re-install the self-hosted agent, then you can change the self-hosted agent name.

Refer to the doc about [the steps to re-install the self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#remove-and-re-configure-an-agent).

I can fully understand your requirement. You can create a suggestion ticket in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report your requirement.